# EC2 Linux Instance - Running python script on instance reboot

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, instance, auto

Could someone point me what I'm doing wrong? I want both of my python scripts to run whenever EC2 instance is rebooted, I'm using AWS EC2 Linux Instance & Cloud 9

I understand thats **Edit user data** needs to be changed in order to achieve this, but i'm not successful, currently I have tried:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
python script.py
python script2.py

--//--
```

But this doesn't help

I referred to this article - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

script.py and script2.py to run when ec2 instance rebooted/launched

Comment: just use systemd...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to put the scripts in:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

This assumes that `cloud-init` is running on the instance, which is the magic that makes User Data scripts work. It is installed by default on Ubuntu and Amazon Linux AMIs.

For an example of running jobs when an instance boots, see: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I checked url you shared, and sorry for stupid question - but how can I access this folder to put scripts there? I'm using EC2 Linux Instance + AWS Cloud 9 virtual computing to run python there.

Comment: Can you open a Command Line via Cloud 9 to access the shall? If so, just copy the files there.

Comment: John thanks, for commenting, i can open terminal from Cloud 9 is there any way i can reach out to you? would much appreciate it

Comment: If you need to download the scripts from somewhere to get them on the instance, I'd recommend putting them in an Amazon S3 bucket. You can then use the AWS CLI (or an AWS SDK) on the instance to download them from S3.